# jQuery is not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

i have code like this, but console.log does not bring anything, when i try to type in the console, i can see it loaded, but when i load this script it does not bring to console anything and jQuery function is not working. Code below:

```
var bbimagebannerfile = "/300x250.jpg";

document.write("<a href=\"%%__REDIRECT%%\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"" + bbimagebannerfile + "\" border=\"0\" /></a>");

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = '//Libraries/ThirdParty/Jquery/1.10.2.min.js';
    jqTag.onload = myJQueryCode;
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
}


console.log(window.jQuery); // Ar jau yra užkrautas jQuery

if ('undefined' !== typeof window.jQuery) {
    console.log(window.jQuery("#Tomas")); // Ar jau yra inicializuotas div'as su ID "Tomas" (wery bad approach)

    var main = function () {
        var t = $("#Tomas").offset().top;

        $(document).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > t)
            {
                $("#Tomas")
                        .css('position', 'fixed') //we change the position to fixed
                        .css('top', 0); // and the top to zero
            } else {
                $("#Tomas")
                        .css('position', 'static') //we change the position to fixed
                        .css('top', 0); // and the top to zero
            }
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(main);
}
```

Comment: Show how do you include jQuery and your script. Probably you include your script before jQuery.

Comment: Seems to trigger fine, must indeed be the library link.

Comment: Script loading is asynchronous. Afaik you try to load jQuery by inserting a new `<script>` tag, but you do not wait for the loading to be finished before accessing the jQuery object.

Comment: There is javascript placed on the webpage, which displays the banner. In this case, that javascript loads this code, which i have pasted BUT it does not bring the console.log on the page. When i am trying it locally, everything works just fine.

Comment: @Sirko how can i fix that ? How to check if the library has finshed loading and then launch the execution of the funciont ?

Comment: You already specify a callback, for when the lib is loaded: `jqTag.onload = myJQueryCode;` Put all your jQuery dependent code in that callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned [Sirko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1169798/sirko) in comments, you already have reference to some callback `myJQueryCode`

I would show just an example of this implementation:

```
var bbimagebannerfile = "/300x250.jpg";

document.write("<a href=\"%%__REDIRECT%%\" target=\"_blank\"><img src=\"" +
  bbimagebannerfile + "\" border=\"0\" /></a>");

var onJqueryLoad = function (flag) {
    if ('undefined' !== typeof window.jQuery) {
        console.log(window.jQuery("#Tomas")); // Ar jau yra inicializuotas div'as su ID "Tomas" (wery bad approach)

        var main = function () {
            var t = $("#Tomas").offset().top;

            $(document).scroll(function () {
                if ($(this).scrollTop() > t) {
                    $("#Tomas")
                      .css('position', 'fixed') //we change the position to fixed
                      .css('top', 0); // and the top to zero
                } else {
                    $("#Tomas")
                      .css('position', 'static') //we change the position to fixed
                      .css('top', 0); // and the top to zero
                }
           });
           if ('function' === typeof myJQueryCode && !flag) {
               myJQueryCode();    
           }
       }

       $(document).ready(main);
   }
}

if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
    var headTag = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var jqTag = document.createElement('script');
    jqTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    jqTag.src = '//Libraries/ThirdParty/Jquery/1.10.2.min.js';
    jqTag.onload = onJqueryLoad;
    headTag.appendChild(jqTag);
}

onJqueryLoad(true);
```

Also you could look at article about [HTMLScriptElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement) on MDN

Comment: thank you very much for your help. This worked like a charm. Also, is it possible to load that file only when user scrolls down and reaches the div ? Only after reaching it the banner file will load and start jQuery script also ?

Comment: In the case of lazy loading of banner I would suggest something like in the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j72jwoks/

Comment: is it possible to combine both scripts. I mean scrollable div and lazy load ? It would be like when user scrolls until that point, the script loads and then become scrollable ?